# Slightly blurry vintage/VHS effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, vintage

I don't know what to call this effect, but I am in love with the look of this: https://vimeo.com/280574752 music video.

Can anybody help me figure out how this effect might be created? I can almost detect a slight VHS effect since there is sometimes a green outline.

Thanks! :)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: I don't know about Photoshop, but there are tons of resources for faking the vhs look in After Effects.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's older than VHS, it mimics the effect created by the film irregular overexposure produced by the incidence of light through the time.

Using this as the original image:

[image: original]

You can add different layers with black and white clouds on top, screen mode, 10% opacity

[image: clouds]

And different backgrounds with Maximum filter effect

[image: maximum]

This is an example with just seven animation frames:

[image: animation]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very close to what I want to achieve!!